# is duplicate variable really BAD?

Tags: php, mysqli

I know that this php code is bad

```
<?php
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

but it saves from writing that long code !
For better readability we have to loss some memory,
**Q-> but is it really bad [if I have 5 such variables in a page] ?**

================================================================

**Q-> which one works faster ?**
 1-> `mysqli_prepare("sql");`
 2-> `mysql_real_escape_string("input");
     mysqli_query("sql");`

================================================================

**Q-> is it efficient to close mysqli after it's job is finished in every page ?**

Comment: What code you are talking about?

Comment: @Deele I guess it's the availability of `$id` (as opposed to `$_SESSION['id']`) after the declaration?!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why your first example would be considered bad, really. I'd do that to, and write `$id` back to `$_SESSION` when I'm done with it. Nothing wrong with that IMHO.

Comment: @Sourav As for Q2: I find it hard to believe that performance is *so* important that it is worth *not* using the safer (and, IMHO, more readable) `mysqli_prepare()`.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, SO does not have threads or discussions, but rather questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q-> but is it really bad [if i have such 5 variable in page] ?**

you should sanitize your input variables!

**Q-> which one works fast ?**

mysqli_prepare() ist faster in most cases

**Q-> is it efficient to close mysqli after it's job is finish in every page ?**

i think it is a good cosing style and should be done!

Answer (score 1):

> but it saves from writing that long code ! For better readability we have to loss some memory,

You should really not be concerned with memory. An empty array eats up more memory than five duplicate string variables.

If it aids the readability, then use localized variable copies. If you don't forget to filter your input variables in that step, then all the better. There's nothing "bad" about this method.

> which one works fast ?  mysqli / mysql_real_escape_string

That depends. If you use prepared statments / bound parameters you can save some time if you send multiple data rows to the DB. For ordinary queries, if you just escape the values with mysqli, it won't make a difference. Mysqli and the old mysql_ functions probably differ in speeds, but it's certainly insignificant in comparison to the database query itself.

> is it efficient to close mysqli after it's job is finish in every page ?

You shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Q-> but is it really bad [if i have such 5 variable in page] ?**

It simply consumes more bytes in memory.
You could create a static class that wraps around your $_SESSION

**Q-> which one works fast ?**
You could test it yourself (counting milliseconds).
I use PDO_MYSQL with Zend_Db.

**Q-> is it efficient to close mysqli after it's job is finish in every page ?**
I actively close all used connections at the end (after the end of a php script, no need to keep them alive or letting them sleep).

Answer (score 0):

1. It is good.
2. neither. speed shouldn't be your concern here.
3. Doesn't matter for the web pages.

Comment: thnx to all for replying, trhnx again :)